# Video learning platform for User Experience Resources

Tags: user-research, learning, e-learning

Having recently made a transition from software development & cloud architecture to a purely User Experience Research & Human Factors role I was wondering if there are suggested video platforms for education on relevant content.

Pluralsight was instrumental in my software development & cloud architecture roles in the past along with other platforms such as Microsoft virtual academy. The Video format is easy to digest especially during a slow walk on the treadmill etc.

I noticed that some platforms like Pluralsight have much less UX-focused content. Are there other platforms one might suggest? I am aware this is possibly opinion-based but would lobby the moderators to allow the question to help foster the spread of information.

Platforms I am aware of

- NN/g youtube channel
- Udemy
- LinkedIn Learning
- Pluralsight
- Interaction Design Foundation

Comment: Interaction Design Foundation is also one

Comment: really appreciate it thank you @Big_Chair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another place you can look for video content that isn't necessarily found within online learning platforms are the websites of companies that develop UX tools (e.g. Adobe XD or Figma or Invision, etc.).

Often these companies produce content specifically relating to the application of their products and services in the context of a UX design or research related work, but if you look beyond that there are often lots of good insights and learnings to be gained as well.